# Clojure - Calculate accumulative sum of vector of maps

Tags: clojure

I want to calculate the accumulative sum of a field in a vector of maps. From:

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :name "John1" :income 5000}
   {:id 2 :name "John2" :income 6000}
   {:id 3 :name "John3" :income 7000}])
```

to:

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :name "John1" :income 5000}
   {:id 2 :name "John2" :income 11000}
   {:id 3 :name "John3" :income 18000}])
```

I have something like `(reductions + (map :income data))`to do the calculation, but how to form the new vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue your solution (and if you don't mind iterating data twice):

```clj
(map #(assoc %1 :income %2) data (reductions + (map :income data)))
; => ({:id 1, :income 5000, :name "John1"}
; =>  {:id 2, :income 11000, :name "John2"}
; =>  {:id 3, :income 18000, :name "John3"})
```

(or `mapv` to keep the vector)

Answer (score 2):

```
> (reduce #(conj %1 (assoc %2 :income (+ (:income (last %1)) (:income %2)))) (vector (first data)) (rest data))
[{:id 1, :name "John1", :income 5000}
 {:id 2, :name "John2", :income 11000}
 {:id 3, :name "John3", :income 18000}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using specter:

`(transform (subselect ALL :income) #(reductions + %) data)`